# I can't populate data from seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, seed

I can't populate my data from seed.rb, when I use `rake db:seed` nothing happens.

- Using Rails 5.
- Data from Rails 4

Can I use this structure in Rails 5?

```
Product.delete_all
Product.create!(title: 'CoffeeScript',
  description: 
    %{<p>
        CoffeeScript is JavaScript done right. It provides all of JavaScript\'s
    functionality wrapped in a cleaner, more succinct syntax. In the first
    book on this exciting new language, CoffeeScript guru Trevor Burnham
    shows you how to hold onto all the power and flexibility of JavaScript
    while writing clearer, cleaner, and safer code.
      </p>},
  image_url:   'cs.jpg',    
  price: 36.00)
# . . .
Product.create!(title: 'Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0',
  description:
    %{<p>
        Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic language
        out there. If you need to get working programs delivered fast,
        you should add Ruby to your toolbox.
      </p>},
  image_url: 'ruby.jpg',
  price: 49.95)



Product.create!(title: 'Rails Test Prescriptions',
  description: 
    %{<p>
        <em>Rails Test Prescriptions</em> is a comprehensive guide to testing
        Rails applications, covering Test-Driven Development from both a
        theoretical perspective (why to test) and from a practical perspective
        (how to test effectively). It covers the core Rails testing tools and
        procedures for Rails 2 and Rails 3, and introduces popular add-ons,
        including Cucumber, Shoulda, Machinist, Mocha, and Rcov.
      </p>},
  image_url: 'rtp.jpg',
  price: 34.95)
```

Comment: There is no change with how seeding works from 4 to 5, so the error must be elsewhere. You try adding some simple debugging to the file and see if it's being run at all. Like `puts 'first line'` at the top, should see that in the console then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Seed Data Loading and Verifying

#### Create a test application

```
$ rails new seedtest
$ cd seedtest
```

#### Add product model

```
$ rails g model product title description image_url price:decimal
$ rails db:migrate
```

#### Prepare the db/seeds.rb file

```
puts 'start loading data'
copy and paste your loading code into db/seeds.rb
puts 'finish loading data'
```

#### Load Seed Data

```
$ rails db:seed
start Loading data
finish Loading data
```

#### Verify

```
$ rails db
sqlite> select * from products;



1|CoffeeScript|
    CoffeeScript is JavaScript done right. It provides all of    JavaScript's
functionality wrapped in a cleaner, more succinct syntax. In the first
book on this exciting new language, CoffeeScript guru Trevor Burnham
shows you how to hold onto all the power and flexibility of JavaScript
while writing clearer, cleaner, and safer code.
  |cs.jpg|36|2017-02-11 10:44:38.648505|2017-02-11 10:44:38.648505
...
...
More data

.exit    # when you've finished
```

[Code on github - with commits using each title](https://github.com/notapatch/seedtest)

Comment: I tried 'rails db:seed' instead 'rake db:seed', also I used the example but still doeasn't works. :|
When I put 'rails db:seed' in command, nothing was printed :/

Comment: `rake db:seed` still works on Rails 5, it wasn't deprecated.